# Rule of spacing between roses and vines

Tags: growth, roots, roses, grape-vine, spacing

For example, If the normal spacing between grape vines is 8 feet, then does that mean that a hybrid tea rose with the recommended spacing of 3 feet would also have to spaced 8 feet away from the grapevine ?

Comment: I would not consider both species as trees. Grape vine is a vine (originally) so it can growth on shadow of a tree (but they it will hike the tree, and just birds will eat grapes). Rose: there are many different kinds, some more like vines, some not (bush is also generic). Note: it is fashionable to plant roses in vineyard: roses will help fighting parasites. Usually there is no competition of roses to grape vine). But your "bush" need some more description.

Comment: "A standard rose bush" is a bit confusing, because there are "standard roses" and "bush roses", but the two types of plant are different shapes and heights.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details about the kind of roses, if you want them to flower and we can reopen

Comment: Your right. I apologize for the confusion. I wanted to say hybrid tea roses that are generally spaced 3 feet apart from on another. How close can it be planted to a grapevine trained onto a pergola? When vines are said to be planted 8 feet apart, does that mean that the roots would need 8 feet of room to grow?